# Java InetAddress.getByName & /etc/hosts

Tags: java, linux, hosts

With

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_72"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_72-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.72-b15, mixed mode)
```

And aliases in the host file like

```
10.0.0.4 bar.com
10.0.0.5 a-a.foo.com a-b.foo.com a-c.foo.com ...
```

Im able to resolve bar.com with InetAddress.getByName("bar.com").
But If the line is getting bigger like 30 hosts and longer than 767 Chars a UnknownHostException is thrown.

How to let Java handle this line as should?

For example "ping bar.com" is doing the lookup correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a limit on the number of aliases per ip address depending on your system.
Try adding another line for each x aliases where x is max number of aliases for your system which is 34 in your case.

https://library.netapp.com/ecmdocs/ECMP1368834/html/GUID-C6F3B6D1-232D-44BB-A76C-3304C19607A3.html

Comment: any idea why this limit applies to the jvm and not to let's say 'ping' ?

Comment: JVM has the same behavior as ping on Windows. If ping cannot access it, neither can the JVM. Are you sure its not the case in Linux ? You're pinging bar.com, try pinging alias number 35 of 10.0.0.5